# How does array_contains work in Snowpark Python API

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

I have the following DataFrame

```
----------
|"ARR"   |
----------
|[       |
|  "A",  |
|  "B",  |
|  "C"   |
|]       |
----------
```

Not I want to check whether a specific element is in ARR:

This gives a Error (failed to execute query...):

```
df\
    .withColumn("contains_A",array_contains("A",col("ARR")))\
    .show()
```

same here

```
df\
    .withColumn("contains_A",array_contains(lit("A"),col("ARR")))\
    .show()
```

and this gives FALSE

```
df\
    .withColumn("contains_A",array_contains(array_construct(lit("A")),col("ARR")))\
    .show()
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you search for in [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_contains.html) must be a variant

```
with t0(arr) as (
    select parse_json('["a","b","c"]')
)
select array_contains('a'::variant, arr) CONTAINS_A
from t0;
```

| CONTAINS_A |
| --- |
| True |

In Snowpark, I believe this should give you what you want:
`df.withColumn("contains_A",sql_expr("array_contains('A'::variant,ARR)")).show()`

Comment: but how to do it in Snowpark Python API? I could not find out how to mark something as a "variant"

Comment: Updated my answer with Snowpark sql_expr code.

Comment: yes with sql_expr it works, but I was looking for an non-SQL solution, but maybe its not possible... thanks anyway

Comment: If you use `lit("B").cast("variant")`, you can do it fully in Snowpark. In the proposed solution, replace the call of `sql_expr` by: 

`array_contains(lit("A").cast("variant"), col("ARR"))`

Comment: @drmaettu How do you use array_contains without sql_expr? This code failed:

`>>> df.withColumn("contains_a",array_contains(lit("A").cast("variant"), col("ARR")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'array_contains' is not defined`